# Работа с картами google

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase

В диалоге с одним из разработчиков он поведал мне "сюжет":

> Есть статичный recyclerview со множеством категорий, где данные хранятся в девайсе. После выбора категории, он подменяется фрагментом Maps, откуда бд по сортировочным параметрам заполняет карту.

Мои размышления:

Я предположил, что всё же лучше по нажатию на каждый элемент списка в recyclerView открывать активити, в которой будет содержаться map.

Во-вторых, для каждой категории правильно было бы заполнять параметрами карту с помощью БД, но т.к. писать с нуля для меня пока еще сложновато, я хотел бы прибегнуть к помощи сервисов. И набрёл я на следующие: **Parse**(который как я понял закрывается 27 января), **Azure**(ничего не могу о нём сказать), ну и фаворит на мой взгляд **FireBase**(который сейчас многие пытаются внедрить в свои приложения, т.к. с помощью него можно обслуживать apps на се 100%).

Подходя к идее, делаю вывод, что мне нужно как то хранить данные в JSON после чего парсить их. Возможно есть замечания/советы, прошу в обсуждения.

*Только начинаю углубляться в работу с картами, так что любым полезным ресурсам примерам буду крайне рад.*

Answer (score 1):

Ну да, все верно. Хранишь Json на сервере FireBase , читаешь и по клику передаешь описание и координаты на активити карты.
У себя делал именно так.
Единственное что у FireBase ограниченные бесплатные тарифы.

Comment: Можно какие то выкладки из кода, для большего понимания что к чему?
Было бы полезнко как для меня так и для будущих читателей.

Comment: Без проблем, что именно вас интересует, напишите я покажу. По сути логика такая -  обычный RecyclerView читаете json с FB, далее putExtra на следующую активити и там открываете как любые другие координаты. Разницы особо нету как получать данные.

Answer (score 0):

1 вопрос: логичнее запускать новое активити, если это должно выглядеть как переход на новый экран. Ваш кейс это подразумевает. 
2 вопрос: (я может не до конца правильно понял вопрос) выборка данных из бд должна быть по параметрам

Comment: @pavel163 обновил вопрос)